# Media queries don't work for mobile IE

Tags: javascript, mobile, windows-mobile

I've defined the following media queries in order to load different `.css` files for mobile and desktop browsers:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="desktop.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="mobile.css" />
```

But in mobile Internet Explorer I see styles from `desktop.css` for some reason. Why it is so? How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe Mobile Internet Explorer doesn't consider itself to be of the "handheld" media type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of `handheld` is not reliable in mobile browsers, some mobile browsers (such as Mobile Internet Explorer) use `media="handheld"` if it is the only value defined, but use `media="screen"` by default if both are defined. The hack is to define `media="Screen"`, with an uppercase `S`, this causes Mobile IE to use the `handheld` option when both are defined.
But I'd suggest you to avoid using these media queries as you should rely on screen resolution rather than on mobile browser. For example, Mobile Safari could be on both iPad or iPhones, but you need to style your webiste differently because of different size of the screen. So you can use the following media queries for iPhones:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" />
```

For iPad

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px)" href="ipad.css" />
```

For desktop

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 960px)" href="desktop.css" />
```

Or you can specify media queries directly in .css file

```
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .class {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Here are some good articles about it:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/03/how-to-build-a-mobile-website/

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 1):

It is being applied because a handheld is also a screen.  Try hiding the desktop version by using a media query such as this:

```
media="screen and (min-device-width:500px)"
```

---

<strike>IE does not recognize `media="handheld"`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530813(VS.85).aspx</strike>  I take that back.  Mobile IE does recognize that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415462.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use css for windows lumia 535

**@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 360px) 
and (max-device-width : 640px) 
and (orientation : portrait) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
}**

Use css for windows lumia 520

**@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
// your code goes here
}**